# Consulta de importacion de archivos en react js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, programación-reactiva

Tengo en mi proyecto CRA la forma en que uso el sistema de carpetas es así, y cuando llamo los archivos tengo que poner

```
import MyArchivoPrueba1 from ./Archivo
import MyArchivoPrueba1 from ./../Archivo 
import MyArchivoPrueba1 from ./../../Carpeta/Archivo
```

¿Hay alguna forma de reducir este proceso y que al importar una imagen, componente, etc sea de esta forma?

```
import MyArchivoPrueba1 from { RutaSRC }/Assets/Archivo
import MyArchivoPrueba2 from { RutaSRC }/Images/Archivo
import MyArchivoPrueba3 from { RutaSRC }/Views/Archivo
```

Quiero evitar estar poniendo los puntos para llamar a un archivo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer eso debes meterte con el path resolver de webpack, si estas usando `create-react-app` debes hacer un `reject` para poder configurar el webpack que trae puesto, si lo haces, [aqui esta una guia](https://moduscreate.com/blog/es6-es2015-import-no-relative-path-webpack/) de como configurarlo

Por el momento sin configurar nada puedes omitir el primer punto, puede reducirse de

```
import MyArchivoPrueba1 from './Archivo';
import MyArchivoPrueba1 from './../Archivo';
import MyArchivoPrueba1 from './../../Carpeta/Archivo';
```

a

```
import MyArchivoPrueba1 from './Archivo';
import MyArchivoPrueba1 from '../Archivo';
import MyArchivoPrueba1 from '../../Carpeta/Archivo';
```

Comment: **Debes hacer un eject** no, **puedes**, sí. No es obligatorio hacer un `eject`; existen librerías para extender el archivo de configuración de Webpack. Por ejemplo, [rescripts](https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts).